# Enable list-style CSS

Tags: css

My master CCS file contains the following property for lists

```
{
list-style: none;
}
```

Please note that I cannot change this property.

In my application I need to generate a list. This will be a dynamically generated list as per the user's input. It can be an ordered or an unordered list or it might not be generated at all.

I want to enable `"list-style"` for this list in case it is generated. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Can you post a sample of the generated list in context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `class` to ul generate dynamically,after than write :

```
.yourClass{
 list-style: disc;
}
```

**OR**

```
.yourClass {
    list-style: disc !important;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("<ul class=yourClass><li>generate dynamically</li></ul>").appendTo("body");
})
```

```css
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

.yourClass {
    list-style: disc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
 <li>Not generate dynamically</li>
</ul>
```